# Use dynamically appended elements with 'on' function without 'events'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't access an hidden alert after dynamically appended from another file with jquery load function. I also appended '#addMovie' button dynamically and learned that I can trigger it with 'on' function, but I cant do same thing on '#alertSuccess' because it has no events like 'click' to use with 'on' function, it is hidden and it will be visible automatically. 
1) How can I update this DOM without 'events' but using 'on' function ?
or 
2) Can I trigger and show this element without 'on' function ?
or
3) Can I update all DOM's after appended and use them with .click function like other existing elements, so I don't need on('click'...) functions anymore ?

```
// Both '#addMovie' and '#alertSuccess' appended dynamically 
// into '#searchMovieDiv' element.

$('#searchMovieDiv').on('click', '#addMovie', function(e){ // can trigger this with 'on'

      ....
      ....
$('#alertSuccess').show(); // can't trigger this with 'on' cause
                          // it has no events, will be visible without condition


      ....
      ....
}

// Appended alert
<div class="alert alert-success" id="alertSuccess">
    <strong>Movie added</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do to, or with, the `#alertSucces` (incidentally: 'success' has a double-'s' at the end) element?

Comment: It is an appended div which I create in separate file with that ID, I want to show that alert

Comment: The `div` with `id="alertSuccess"` should become visible the moment you call `$('#alertSuccess').show();` if it exists by the time you call this `show()`, if all DOM elements in its parent chain are visible and if its `id` is unique. The last condition, I suspect, is the problem.

Comment: If I append all this codes by hand to original file without 'load' function, this alert shows, but if I add all this elements with 'load' function, I have to use 'on' function to trigger them. So show() function doesnt make them visible when this div added by load() function

Comment: I do not see the 'load' function that you are referring to, so I have nothing new to say.

Comment: cause those elements appended after load function is called, I didn't see the reason to write down 'load' function

Comment: Dynamic binding of events is needed so that you can set up a general event handler once, and then add and remove matching elements dynamically. You don't need it for something like `.show()` -- just put that in the function that creates the new element.